# WordPress Debug: WP_Http & Notice | briarnblaar.co.za | Critical Error Screen

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging, bbpress

I have a Pipe Smokers forum briarnblaar.co.za - which I created on WordPress using the disputo theme and bbPress forum.

My site frequently gives a white screen with a critical error message and then I need to reload the screen.  I installed the Debug bar, enabled WP_DEBUG and when I go to my page, I see a white banner with the following message:

> Notice: Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object in /home/briardsj/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 4027
>
> Notice: Trying to get property 'post_title' of non-object in /home/briardsj/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 4029
>
> Notice: Trying to get property 'post_name' of non-object in /home/briardsj/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 4031
>
> Notice: Trying to get property 'post_type' of non-object in /home/briardsj/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 4179"

When I click on the debug button, I get

A warning:

> NOTICE: wp-content/plugins/disputo-features/so-widgets/disputo-forums/tpl/disputo-forums-template.php:21 - Undefined variable: disputo_thumbnail
> require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/disputo/page_template_2.php'), the_content, apply_filters('the_content'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, SiteOrigin_Panels->generate_post_content, SiteOrigin_Panels_Renderer->render, SiteOrigin_Panels_Renderer->render_row, SiteOrigin_Panels_Renderer->render_cell, SiteOrigin_Panels_Renderer->render_widget, SiteOrigin_Panels_Renderer->the_widget, SiteOrigin_Widget->widget, include('/plugins/disputo-features/so-widgets/disputo-forums/tpl/disputo-forums-template.php')

I also get a message under the WP_Http tab:

```
[class] => Requests
[stack_trace] => Array
        (
            [0] => Debug_Bar_WP_Http->after_http_request
            [1] => WP_Hook->apply_filters
            [2] => WP_Hook->do_action
            [3] => do_action('http_api_debug')
            [4] => WP_Http->request
            [5] => WP_Http->post
            [6] => wp_remote_post
            [7] => spawn_cron
            [8] => wp_cron
            [9] => WP_Hook->apply_filters
            [10] => WP_Hook->do_action
            [11] => do_action('init')
            [12] => require_once('wp-settings.php')
            [13] => require_once('wp-config.php')
            [14] => require_once('wp-load.php')
            [15] => require_once('wp-admin/admin.php')
```

I have no coding knowledge nor experience.  Can someone please in laymen's terms tell me what should I do to get this sorted?

I would really appreciate any help.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hey Johannes, those "Warnings" and data posted above are with 99.99% probability NOT the reason for your white screen error. That's why they are Warnings, meant for devs to know they are there and account for those cases, but not breaking either.

If you want to get help, what you need is the information from the critical error message, that's what will indicate where the breaking issue is.

Didn't WordPress send you an email with the details of the errror?

Comment: @Tami - thank you for that comment.  The screen does tell me that I need to check my inbox for an email from WordPress - but till now I haven't received anything.  What do you suggest, where should I look for the erro?

Comment: Hey there, if you're not receiving that email, you probably have your email server not configured or not configured correctly. Would you be able to edit a WordPress file, like via FTP, to work around this?